# Javascript to get MM/DD values for each weekday in a range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The following javascript code creates a weekly calendar that gives me the startDate & endDate:  [Weekly Calendar Widget](http://jsfiddle.net/manishma/AVZJh/light/)

- How do I adapt it to also give me the MM/DD values for each weekday in the range?
- For example I need to get the following variables out to my form:

  - var startDate; (ex.. 11/10/2013)
  - var endDate; (ex.. 11/16/2013)
  - var sunDate; (need.. 11/10)
  - var monDate; (need.. 11/11)
  - var tueDate; (need.. 11/12)
  - var wedDate; (need.. 11/13)
  - var thuDate; (need.. 11/14)
  - var friDate; (need.. 11/15)
  - var satDate; (need.. 11/16)

### Would it be something like..?

var sunDate = endDate - 6 (Formatted mm/dd)

### Here is the javascript calendar code:

```
see link: Weekly Calendar Widget
```

### Here is my updated code that ended up working for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var startDate;
var endDate;
var monDate;
var tueDate;
var wedDate;
var thuDate;
var friDate;
var satDate;
var sunDate;
var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
    }, 1);
}

$('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd",
    firstDay: 1, // Start with Monday
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 7);
        monDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
        tueDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 2);
        wedDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 3);
        thuDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 4);
        friDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 5);
        satDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        sunDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 7);
        var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
        $('#startDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#endDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#monDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, monDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#tueDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, tueDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#wedDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, wedDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#thuDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, thuDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#friDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, friDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#satDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, satDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#sunDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, sunDate, inst.settings ));
        selectCurrentWeek();
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var cssClass = '';
        if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
            cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
        return [true, cssClass];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        selectCurrentWeek();
    }
});

$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
</script>
```

### Then in my HTML I used:

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Mon<br>
    <input disabled id="monDate" size="5" data-mini="true"></th>
  <th>Tue<br>
    <input disabled id="tueDate" size="5" data-mini="true"></th>
  <th>Wed<br>
    <input disabled id="wedDate" size="5" data-mini="true"></th>
  <th>Thu<br>
    <input disabled id="thuDate" size="5" data-mini="true"></th>
  <th>Fri<br>
    <input disabled id="friDate" size="5" data-mini="true"></th>
  <th>Sat<br>
    <input disabled id="satDate" size="5" data-mini="true"></th>
  <th>Sun<br>
    <input disabled id="sunDate" size="5" data-mini="true"></th>
  <th>Totals</th>
  <th>Description</th>
</tr>
```

Here is my full HTML page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58096637/Timesheet.txt

Comment: In the posted code you're using jQuery 1.4, is this a requirement? That one is pretty old.

Comment: I updated my answer with code that should work better, can't test it because don't have the full html page. If you change the firstDay variable to anything but 1 I think your code stops displaying correct days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

In your code:

```
$('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm",
```

Your code looks fine but only works if firstDay is 1, **Updated the code to work with the html you provided**

```
$(function() {
  //removed all variables
  var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a')
        .addClass('ui-state-active')
    }, 1);
  }

  //changed this function
  $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd",
    firstDay: 1, // Start with Monday
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
      start = inst.settings.firstDay || $.datepicker._defaults.firstDay,
      year = date.getFullYear(),month = date.getMonth(),
      day = (date.getDate()-date.getDay()),
      elIds=["#monDate","#tueDate","#wedDate","#thuDate","#friDate","#satDate",
        "#sunDate","#startDate","#endDate"],
      i=-1,start,dates=[],
      dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || 
        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
      day=(date.getDay()<start)?(day+start)-7:day+start;
      while(++i<7){
        dates.push(new Date(year,month,day+i));
        $(elIds[i]).val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, dates[i]
          , inst.settings ));
      }
      i=-1;
      $(elIds[7]).val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, dates[0],
        inst.settings ));
      $(elIds[8]).val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, dates[6],
        inst.settings ));
      selectCurrentWeek();
    },
  });
  $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mousemove', function() {
    $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); 
  });
  $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I'm still not clear how to actually populate the dates on my form?

Comment: I need to change my static dates below to dynamic values from the calendar picker..

Here is a section of my page 
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Mon<br>
        11/04</th>
      <th>Tue<br>
        11/05</th>
      <th>Wed<br>
        11/06</th>
      <th>Thu<br>
        11/07</th>
      <th>Fri<br>
        11/08</th>
      <th>Sat<br>
        11/09</th>
      <th>Sun<br>
        11/10</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>

(using jquery-1.8.3, jquery-ui-1.10.0, jquery.mobile-1.3.0)

Comment: I do like your simplification but it didn't work..

It stops on this line: i=-1,index,start, saying:Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined

ps: I attached my full HTML page in a link on my original post. I'm still learning JavaScript..

Comment: @jlig I've updated the answer, worked out the bugs when using your html page. The only dynamic part is the calendar (you can change firstDay), if you want the bottom part to be dynamic too then you'll need to generate the table based on the firstDay value and elIds. This could be done by selecting them and re inserting them. Since your application always uses monday as the first day this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I add to the Date prototype, `addSeconds(seconds)`, `subtractSeconds(seconds)`, and `format(some_format)`. The format function uses exactly the same formats as MySQL [DATE_FORMAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Example... starting from startDate in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishma/AVZJh/light/)

```
var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
for (var x = 1; x <= 7; ++x) {
  // add 1 day (in seconds)
  startDate.addSeconds(24 * 60 * 60);
  alert("day " + x + " = " + startDate.format("%m/%d"));
}
```

And copy and paste all this code which extends what the Date object can do.

```
/**
 * Add a number of seconds to the current date
 * @return Date The date object
 */
Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds) {
  var time = this.getTime();
  alert("time = " + time);
  time += seconds * 1000;
  this.setTime(time);
  return this;
}

/**
 * Subtract a number of seconds to the current date
 * @return Date The date object
 */
Date.prototype.subtractSeconds = function(seconds) {
  var time = this.getTime();
  alert("time = " + time);
  time -= seconds * 1000;
  this.setTime(Math.max(0, time));
  return this;
}

/**
 * DATE
 *   format() - uses MySQL date formatting... a few of the more obscure formats are left unfinished
 */
Date.prototype.format = function(format) {
  var short_months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var short_days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

  var escaped = false;
  var pieces = new Array();
  for (var x = 0; x < format.length; ++x) {
    if (!escaped) {
      if (format.charAt(x) != "%") {
        pieces.push(format.charAt(x));
      } else {
        escaped = true;
      }
      continue;
    }

    switch (format.charAt(x)) {
    case "a":
      pieces.push(short_days[this.getDay()]); break;
    case "b":
      pieces.push(short_months[this.getMonth()]); break;
    case "c":
      pieces.push(Number(this.getMonth()) + 1); break;
    case "D":
      pieces.push(this.getDate()); break;
    case "d":
      var day_of_month = new String(this.getDate());
      pieces.push(day_of_month.pad(2, "0")); break;
    case "e":
      pieces.push(this.getDate()); break;
    case "f":
      var microseconds = new String(this.getMilliseconds() * 1000);
      pieces.push(microseconds.pad(6, "0")); break;
    case "H":
      pieces.push(this.getHours()); break;
    case "h":
      var hours = this.getHours() % 12;
      hours = (hours == 0) ? "12" : new String(hours);
      pieces.push(hours.pad(2, "0")); break;
    case "I":
      var hours = this.getHours() % 12;
      hours = (hours == 0) ? "12" : new String(hours);
      pieces.push(hours.pad(2, "0")); break;
    case "i":
      var minutes = new String(this.getMinutes());
      pieces.push(minutes.pad(2, "0")); break;
    case "j": // day of the year 001...365
      pieces.push("???"); break;
    case "k":
      pieces.push(this.getHours()); break;
    case "l":
      var hours = this.getHours() % 12;
      pieces.push((hours == 0) ? "12" : hours); break;
    case "M":
      pieces.push(months[this.getMonth()]); break;
    case "m":
      var month = new String(Number(this.getMonth()) + 1);
      pieces.push(month.pad(2, "0")); break;
    case "p":
      pieces.push((this.getHours() < 12) ? "AM" : "PM"); break;
    case "r": // 12-hour hh:mm:ss AM/PM
      pieces.push("?"); break;
    case "S": case "s":
      pieces.push(this.getSeconds()); break;
    case "T": // 24-hour hh:mm:ss
      pieces.push("?"); break;
    case "u": case "U":
    case "v": case "V":
      pieces.push("?"); break;
    case "W":
      pieces.push(days[this.getDay()]); break;
    case "w":
      pieces.push(this.getDay()); break;
    case "x": case "X": // year for the week w/sunday or monday starting???
      pieces.push("?"); break;
    case "Y":
      pieces.push(this.getFullYear()); break;
    case "y":
      var full_year = new String(this.getFullYear());
      pieces.push(full_year.substr(2, 2)); break;
    default:
      pieces.push(format.charAt(x)); break;
    }
    escaped = false;
  }

  return pieces.join("");
}
```

Comment: Andy, thanks for the detailed code.. But how do I actually "get" the variables for "sunDate thru satDate" so I can use them on my form?

Comment: Are you sure that adding 24 * 60 * 60 seconds to a date gets you to the next day? What if DST starts and the clock is set back one hour?

Comment: It does provided that your system clock is correct - getTime() returns the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC - the timezone is always UTC

Comment: @HMR 
I was able to get the MM/DD values to update properly.. thanks for the help! (see my updated code above)